# Problem in understanding a concept related to partial derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f : \mathbb R^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function of two real variables $x$ and $y$.Where $x$ and $y$ are themselves function of a real variable $t$.Suppose $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \vert_{(x(c),y(c))}$ exists for some $c \in \mathbb R$.Then is the following true?

$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \vert_{(x(c),y(c))} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x(c + h),y(c + h)) - f(x(c),y(c + h))} {x(c + h) - x(c)}$$.

If the answer is 'yes' please explain.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried to edit it to make it clear. But not successful. Please check yourself.

Comment: If you're going to evaluate the partial wrt $\;x\;$ then $\;y\;$ doesn't move...Only $\;x\;$ does.

Comment: But @DonAntonio
$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} \vert_{(x(c),y(c))} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x(c) + t,y(c)) - f(x(c),y(c))} {t}$$.
I fail to relate this concept to the above.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can clear up some things here. By definition,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0):=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)}h$$

Now, since $\;x=x(t)\;$ is a function of $\;t\;$ (and likewise for $\;y\;$ if you will), then $\;x_0=x(c)\;$ , for some value $\;t_0=c\;$ , so $\;x\to x_0\iff t\to t_0\;$, and we can thus write:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0):=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{f(x(t),y(t_0))-f(x(t_0),y(t_0))}{t-t_0}$$

Comment: But @Don the second component of $f$ i.e. $y(c + t)$ is not a constant as $y_{0}$.Which actually creates my problem.If you can clear it then done!

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. I can't understand from what you deduce the second component isn't a constant in the above calculations...

Comment: Can you anyhow transform the limit
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x(c + t),y(c + t)) - f(x(c),y(c + t))} {t}$$
by the limit
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x(c) + h,y(c)) - f(x(c),y(c))} {h}$$?
Which I try to find out for a long period of time because it can ease my purpose.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. I really don't understand why you think that upper limit has *anything* at all to do with partial derivatives, and I don't know what the lower down is...

Comment: what do you mean by upper limit?

Comment: THe first one you wrote in your last comment ...sigh.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I have some misconception.I think you have done your level best.But I am so much dull that I can't grasp it clearly.Whatever can you provide me some link where I can find such things in a rigorous manner?Then I will try.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. Google it. The few first links shall be more than enough for you to see several definitions, examples and etc.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you once again.My last question is "For the existence of the partials is it necessary that both the functions $x$ and $y$ are continuous?"

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. That's true since otherwise the function $\;f(x,y)\;$ would be continuous somewhere and thus, of course, the partials can't exist there.

Comment: I don't understand the logic "otherwise the function would be continuous......"

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. It should have nbeen "wouldn't be continuous" ...